# How to send and receive arrays using an MPI struct in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm attempting to package 1D and 2D double precision arrays in an MPI struct in Fortran 90. I've successfully done this in C++ in a very similar problem and the procedure seems to be almost exactly the same, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong here, despite the extremely helpful MPI error codes...

My best guess is that the problem is in the block length or displacement calculations. The code compiles and runs when the call to MPI_RECV() is commented out, but results in an error when it is uncommented.

main.f90

```
program main
    use mymodule

    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nPROC, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myID, ierr)

    call PASS_MESH_MPI()

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end program
```

mymodule.f90

```
module mymodule
use mpi

double precision, dimension(:,:) :: U(0:10,0:10)
double precision, dimension(:) :: r(0:10), z(0:10)
integer, public :: ierr, nPROC, nWRs, myID, stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

type mytype
      double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: U
      double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: r
      double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: z
end type


contains

subroutine PASS_MESH_MPI()
implicit none
type(mytype) :: package
integer :: blocklen(3), types(3), myMPItype
integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: displacement(3), base

    allocate( package%U(0:10,0:10) )
    allocate( package%r(0:10) )
    allocate( package%z(0:10) )

    call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(package%U, displacement(1), ierr)
    call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(package%r, displacement(2), ierr)
    call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(package%z, displacement(3), ierr)

    base = displacement(1)
    displacement(1) = displacement(1) - base
    displacement(2) = displacement(2) - base
    displacement(3) = displacement(3) - base

    blocklen(1) = (11)*(11)
    blocklen(2) = 11
    blocklen(3) = 11

    types(1) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
    types(2) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
    types(3) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION

    call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(3, blocklen, displacement, types, myMPItype, ierr)
    call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(myMPItype, ierr)

    if ( myID .eq. 0 ) then
        U(:,:) = 5
        r(:) = 5
        z(:) = 5
        package%r(:) = r(:)
        package%z(:) = z(:)
        package%U(:,:) = U(:,:)

        call MPI_SEND(package, 1, myMPItype, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    end if

    if ( myID .ne. 0 ) then
        call MPI_RECV(package, 1, myMPItype, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stat, ierr)
    end if

    call MPI_TYPE_FREE( myMPItype, ierr )

end subroutine
end module
```

makefile

```
COMP=mpif90
EXT=f90
CFLAGs=-Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-interface -fPIC -fmax-errors=1 -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace

PROG=TESTDAT.x
INPUT=input.dat
OUTPUT=output

TARGS=main.f90 mymodule.f90
OBJS=main.o mymodule.o

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

mymodule.mod: mymodule.f90 mymodule.o
    $(COMP) -c $(CFLAGS) mymodule.f90

mymodule.o: mymodule.f90
    $(COMP) -c $(CFLAGS) mymodule.f90

main.o: main.f90 mymodule.mod
    $(COMP) -c $(CFLAGS) main.f90

run:
    make
    mpiexec -np 2 $(PROG)
    make clean

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) *.mod *.o DONE watch
```

Here is the error when I attempt to run this code with 2 processes.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x1020d86fd
#1  0x1020d7a93
#2  0x7fff6f520b5c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node MacBook-Pro exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I've seen this somewhat less descriptive one appear as well.

```
Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x1046906fd
#1  0x10468fa93
#2  0x7fff6f520b5c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node MacBook-Pro exited on signal 6 (Abort trap: 6).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I realize the instructions explicitly say to not paste full files, but these are quite small and I was hoping to make it more convenient for anyone who wanted to run the code themselves. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use `package%U(0,0)` as the buffer parameter of `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`

Comment: Interesting. In C++, the struct itself is used as the buffer parameter. Using only the first type element here makes less sense to me, but it worked! Thank you very much, Gilles!

Comment: I am a bit skeptical by your comment on C++. that can work if you declare `double U[11][11];`, but if you declare `double *U;`, then you will likely face the same issue than in Fortran in which `U` is declared as `allocatable`.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I stand corrected. In C++, &package would be used as the buffer parameter, NOT package. So the input is essentially the same in both languages. Thanks again for your help, Gilles!

Comment: @ClintJordan No, in C++ you alo need the ppointer to the array, not just the containing struct. Perhaps it warrants a full answer or a link to a duplicate but I do not have time to either. To understand the issue, print yourself the addresses of package, package%U, package%r and package%z. It is not necessary to use the first element here.